# WORD Tables and Text not Importing correctly into Design

Tags: adobe-indesign, tables

I am importing a 120-page WORD document into INDESIGN. I am using the IMPORT OPTION settings to import with tables formatting and all. Unfortunately, some tables and images are not importing correctly as if the text and tables are not anchored. How do I fix this without retyping?

Comment: About retaining Word formatting in InDesign take a look at this [page](https://indesignsecrets.com/retaining-important-formatting-when-importing-word-documents.php)

Comment: Welcome to Graphic Design SE. Unfortunately your question does not seem to be answerable without more specifications (can you show us screenshots) and access to the respective files. If you can, please [edit] your question to address this.